# Python 2.7 ConfigParser with no delimiter

Tags: python-2.7, config, delimiter, ini

Using Python 2.7.x and ConfigParser, how to generate a config file as follows?

```
[Section]
key1
key2
key3
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the python documentation.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()


config.add_section('Section')
config.set('Section', 'key1', '')
config.set('Section', 'key2', '')
config.set('Section', 'key3', '')

# Writing our configuration file to 'example.cfg'
with open('example.cfg', 'wb') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Comment: It produces the following output `[Section]
key1 = 
key2 = 
key3 = 
` Is there anyway to strip **=** from it

Answer (score 0):

`=` is part of the format so you cannot tell configparser to omit it.

But you can fool the writer by passing a `io.BytesIO()` object and strip off the spaces+equal sign when writing to a real file.

Self-contained example:

```
import ConfigParser,io

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

config.add_section('Section')
for i in range(1,4):
    config.set('Section', 'key{}'.format(i), '')

# Writing our configuration file to 'example.cfg'
b = io.BytesIO()
config.write(b)   # write in a fake file

# now write the modified contents to a real file
with open('output.ini', 'w') as f:
    for l in b.getvalue().splitlines():
        f.write(l.rstrip("= ")+"\n")
```